# ionic app not working in android version 4.4.2 kitkat

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to run my ionic app on real device it's show login page but connect to server it's till show login page "this request has no response data available" and other device app work fine.

**ionic info:**

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.13 (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.7
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.1.1

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 8.1.1 (cordova-lib@8.1.0)
   Cordova Platforms : android 7.1.4
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 4 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.8.1
   native-run  : 0.3.0

System:

   NodeJS : v10.11.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.13.4
   OS     : Windows 10
```

thanks

Comment: You mean the api response of login is not making the request or making the request but not returning data?

Comment: Try this Plugin: https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib issue was not solve

Comment: Please Tell More About your IONIC CLI and Device details.

Comment: Device details are: Model number "DOMO slate SL32" it's tab version 4.4.2 CONIC CLI:  5.4.13

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib console error:Viewport argument key "viewport-fit" not recognized and ignored. :10 deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds. cordova.js:1219 Channel not fired: onDOMContentLoaded cordova.js:1212 Ionic Native: deviceready did not fire within 5000ms. This can happen when plugins are in an inconsistent state. Try removing plugins from plugins/ and reinstalling them. vendor-es5.js:86774 Ionic Native: deviceready event fired after 5587 ms vendor-es5.js:86769 Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode. vendor-es5.js:63982